# how to pass an database exists in Postgresql server using python

Tags: python, database, postgresql

how to pass an database exists in `Postgresql` server using python after running Python Desktop App again
my code :

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT


conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='postgres' user='postgres' 
password='root'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
conn.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
print("Default Database Coonected successfully")

 
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("create database woooow")
print("New Database Created Successfully")

conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='woooow' user='postgres' 
password='root'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

cursor.close() 
conn.close()
print("New Database DeCoonected successfully")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query the `pg_database` catalog table to check if a database with a given name exists.

The following will return one row with one Boolean column `database_exits` indicating whether a database named `woooow` exists or not.

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM pg_database
                      WHERE datname = 'woooow') database_exits;
```